# Ant Design table continues to show loading even when the table is populated by data

Tags: reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant design in my front end project. I have a table component, which gets populated by data from an API. It takes some time to fetch the data, so I want to show a loading spinner.

```
<Table
  columns={queueColumns}
  dataSource={queueData}
  loading={{ indicator: <div><Spin /></div>}} 
/>
```

My problem is, even after the table is loaded with the data, my table continues to show the loading spinner.

How can I make the spinner vanish when the table is filled with data?

I suspect I would need to put a condition in loading prop of the Table component. But I'm not sure how to go about that

---

Edit: I'm fetching data like this:

```
    const [queueData, setQueueData] = useState('');

    useEffect(() => {        
        var config = {
          method: 'GET',
          url: '/api/queues',
          headers: { 
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
          }
        };
        axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            setQueueData(response.data)
        }) 
      }, [])
```

Comment: how do you get the data source? please share the whole script

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim I just added that in the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately there is a lack of documentation for Ant's `Table` component. To indicate that your table is loading or not you can pass `loading={true}` or `loading={false}`. To set custom spinner you can set `loading={{indicator: <MyBeautifulSpinner/>, spinning: true/false}}`. that `spinning` property indicates that whether table is in loading mode or not. You need to have a state, which is altered after data is fetched. See more on Ant's table `loading`:

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/blob/master/components/table/Table.tsx#L457

Comment: Instead of having ` new state you can also use `!queueData` to indicate that data is still loading. But using that you should also consider error handling and data correction stuff too.

Comment: Great news. Unfortunately their bug report system is so uncomfortable. It would be very nice of you if you could devote some time to create an issues for them to update the documentation, or go ahead yourself and contribute to their documentation if you could understand the code.

Comment: Sure. I will try to do that when I get the time! :)

Answer (score 3):

To show loader/spinner while fetching date from the server, add the loading property to the Antd table I.E:

```
loading={{ indicator: <div><Spin /></div>, spinning:!queueData}}
```